# Как перегенерировать app.min.js на проекте с кастомным Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, битрикс, frontend

Есть файл app.js из которого, в том числе, берется app.min.js. Проект на Битрикс, Vuе, соотвественно подключается app.min.js. Как я понимаю он должен генерироваться при сборке Vue, а как сделать сборку хз... посмотрел, почитал документацию еще стоит symfony/console пытался как то через нее сделать сборку но нечего не получилось, через js bitrix build -w, тоже нечего не получается :( Как перегенерить app.min.js?

Можно ли как то точечно перегенировать только файл app.js и дополнить переписать app.min.js? Или как сделать сборку Vue на Битрикс что бы пеересобрались все файлы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: app.js у вас не файл а папка в которой находиться файл app.min.js

Comment: @DovgalDima  А как мне его сгенерить в min.js

Comment: Команда npm run build в проекте на Vue.js используется для компиляции и сборки вашего приложения Vue.js в готовый для развертывания продукт. Для использования команды npm run build, у вас должен быть настроен файл package.json вашего проекта со скриптами, и в этом файле должен быть определен скрипт с именем "build". Обычно этот скрипт будет использовать инструменты сборки, такие как Webpack или Vite.